# how many records have a column value longer than 400 characters?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have field in the table which I have set to `max` size. I need to know how many records have crossed over 400 char in length.

I need to transfer this data into another table where the size is set to 400. I need to know how many records could get truncated.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LEN(MyField) > 400
```

Note differences in [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) and [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) about trailing spaces etc